# How to fix loading order of javascript files for Pixi overlay for leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, pixi.js

I never used plugins for leaflet before but I have a ton of points I'd like to plot without performance issues. After doing some research I found the PixiOverlay plugin to be the solution. However, after following the readme on the github page I'm receiving the following errors.

**From the web console:**

```
Error: Pixi.js must be loaded first
Loading failed for the <script> with source “...Plugins/pixi.min.js”
Error: Pixi.js must be loaded first
ReferenceError: PIXI is not defined
```

**Index html file with scripts located within the `<body>` tags:**

```
<!--PIXI OVERLAY FOR LOTS OF POINTS-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-pixi-overlay@1.8.1/L.PixiOverlay.min.js"></script>
<script src="Plugins/pixi.min.js"></script>
<script src="Plugins/L.PixiOverlay.min.js"></script>
```

**Javascript file for leaflet (`geojsonData` being my long/lat points):**

```
// sets map starting location
var map = L.map('map',{
    center: [39.20, -105.78],
    zoom: 8,
    minZoom: 2,
    maxZoom: 18,
    attributionControl: false,
});

var pixiOverlay = L.pixiOverlay(function(geojsonData) {
}, new PIXI.Container());

pixiOverlay.addTo(map);
```

Does this plugin require Node.js? I noticed in the directions for installation it has an NPM. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see an error message like

> Error: Pixi.js must be loaded first

Then your loading order should be `Pixi.js` first, i.e.:

```
<script src="Plugins/pixi.min.js"></script>          <!-- this shall load 1st --> 
<script src="Plugins/L.PixiOverlay.min.js"></script> <!-- this shall load 2nd -->
```

---

If you see an error message like

> Loading failed for the `<script>` with source “...Plugins/pixi.min.js”

Then you should check that your webserver is serving that file properly. The ["network" section of your browser's developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) are your friend.

Comment: Ahh upon further investigation I misunderstood the readme on the github page. pixi.js also needs to be pulled not just the leaflet plugin. Thats why it kept throwing that error because the pixi leaflet plugin was looking for pixi.js. Now i need to figure out why the points arn't appearing..